# Access Violation! Inaccessible Value Serial.pas

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a problem with my Serial.pas file, as I am trying to access Com Ports, I am getting access violations and then for the variable hCommPort it says its inaccessible value. At the bottom of this post, the very bottom is the code I use to send my com port and baud rate to Serial.pas.

I have looked all over the place to find a solution for it but I can't seem to find or I just don't have the know how to fix it and it seems I have no knowledge about access violations as I have not dealt with them before.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Here is the whole code for Serial.pas

```
unit Serial;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes,
  Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs;

// This is the Device Control Block record.
// It is the structure that contains the
// serial port setup parameters. This
// structure must be initialized before the
// serial port can be used.  It is declared
// in the windows.pas unit and looks like this:
{type TDCB = record
       DCBLength:DWord;
       Baudrate:DWord;
       Flags:LongInt;
       wReserved:Word;
       XONLim:Word;
       XOFFLim:Word;
       ByteSize:Byte;
       Parity:Byte;
       StopBits:Byte;
       XONChar:Char;
       XOFFChar:Char;
       ErrorChar:Char;
       EOFChar:Char;
       EvtChar:Char;
       wReserved1:Word;
end;}

type
  // You can't do anything without a comm port.
  TCommPort = (cpCOM1, cpCOM2, cpCOM3, cpCOM4,
               cpCOM5, cpCOM6, cpCOM7, cpCOM8, cpCOM9);

  // All of the baud rates that the DCB supports.
  TBaudRate = (br110, br300, br600, br1200, br2400, br4800, br9600,
               br14400, br19200, br38400, br56000, br115200, br128000, br256000, br009600);

  // Parity types for parity error checking
  TParityType = (pcNone, pcEven, pcOdd, pcMark, pcSpace);

  TStopBits = (sbOne, sbOnePtFive, sbTwo);

  TDataBits = (db4, db5, db6, db7, db8);

  TFlowControl = (fcNone, fcXON_XOFF, fcRTS_CTS, fcDSR_DTR);

  // Two new notify events.
  TNotifyTXEvent = procedure(Sender : TObject; data : string) of object;
  TNotifyRXEvent = procedure(Sender : TObject; data : string) of object;

  // Set some constant defaults.
// These are the qquivalent of
// COM2:9600,N,8,1;
const
  dflt_CommPort = cpCOM2;
  dflt_BaudRate = br9600;
  dflt_ParityType = pcNone;
  dflt_ParityErrorChecking = False;
  dflt_ParityErrorChar = 0;
  dflt_ParityErrorReplacement = False;
  dflt_StopBits = sbOne;
  dflt_DataBits = db8;
  dflt_XONChar = $11;  {ASCII 11h}
  dflt_XOFFChar = $13; {ASCII 13h}
  dflt_XONLim = 1024;
  dflt_XOFFLim = 2048;
  dflt_ErrorChar = 0; // For parity checking.
  dflt_FlowControl = fcNone;
  dflt_StripNullChars = False;
  dflt_EOFChar = 0;

type
  TSerialPort = class(TComponent)
  private
    hCommPort : THandle; // Handle to the serial port.
    fCommPort : TCommPort;
    fBaudRate : TBaudRate;
    fParityType : TParityType;
    fParityErrorChecking : Boolean;
    fParityErrorChar : Byte;
    fParityErrorReplacement : Boolean;
    fStopBits : TStopBits;
    fDataBits : TDataBits;
    fXONChar : byte;  {0..255}
    fXOFFChar : byte; {0..255}
    fXONLim : word;  {0..65535}
    fXOFFLim : word; {0..65535}
    fErrorChar : byte;
    fFlowControl : TFlowControl;
    fStripNullChars : Boolean;  // Strip null chars?
    fEOFChar : Byte;
    fOnTransmit : TNotifyTXEvent;
    fOnReceive : TNotifyRXEvent;
    fAfterTransmit : TNotifyTXEvent;
    fAfterReceive : TNotifyRXEvent;
    ReadBuffer : String; // Where the results from the read goes.
    procedure SetCommPort(CP : TCommPort);
    procedure SetBaudRate(BR : TBaudRate);
    procedure SetParityType(PT : TParityType);
    procedure SetParityErrorChecking(SPEC : Boolean);
    procedure SetParityErrorChar(PEC : Byte);
    procedure SetParityErrorReplacement(PER : Boolean);
    procedure SetStopBits(SSB: TStopBits);
    procedure SetDataBits(SDB : TDataBits);
    procedure SetXONChar(SXC : byte);
    procedure SetXOFFChar(SXOC : byte);
    procedure SetXONLim(SXOL : word);
    procedure SetXOFFLim(SXFL : word);
    procedure SetErrorChar(SEC : byte);
    procedure SetFlowControl(SFC : TFlowControl);
    procedure SetStripNullChars(SSNC : Boolean);
    procedure SetEOFChar(SEOFC : Byte);
    procedure Initialize_DCB;
  protected
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function OpenPort(MyCommPort : TCommPort) : Boolean;
    function ClosePort : boolean;
    procedure SendData(data : PChar; size : DWord);
    function GetData : String;
    function InputBufferCount: LongInt;
    function PortIsOpen : boolean;
    procedure FlushTX;
    procedure FlushRX;
  published
    property CommPort : TCommport read fCommPort
                                  write SetCommPort
                                  default dflt_CommPort;
    property BaudRate : TBaudRate read fBaudRate
                                  write SetBaudRate
                                  default dflt_BaudRate;
    property ParityType : TParityType read fParityType
                                      write SetParityType
                                      default dflt_ParityType;
    property ParityErrorChecking : Boolean read fParityErrorChecking
                                           write SetParityErrorChecking
                                           default dflt_ParityErrorChecking;
    property ParityErrorChar : Byte read fParityErrorChar
                                    write SetParityErrorChar
                                    default dflt_ParityErrorChar;
    property ParityErrorReplacement : Boolean read fParityErrorReplacement
                                              write
SetParityErrorReplacement
                                              default
dflt_ParityErrorReplacement;
    property StopBits : TStopBits read fStopBits
                                  write SetStopBits
                                  default dflt_StopBits;
    property DataBits : TDataBits read fDataBits
                                  write SetDataBits
                                  default dflt_DataBits;
    property XONChar : byte read fXONChar
                            write SetXONChar
                            default dflt_XONChar;
    property XOFFChar : byte read fXOFFChar
                            write SetXOFFChar
                            default dflt_XOFFChar;
    property XONLim : word read fXONLim
                           write SetXONLim
                           default dflt_XONLim;
    property XOFFLim : word read fXOFFLim
                           write SetXOFFLim
                           default dflt_XOFFLim;
    property ErrorChar : byte read fErrorChar
                              write SetErrorChar
                              default dflt_ErrorChar;
    property FlowControl : TFlowControl read fFlowControl
                                        write SetFlowControl
                                        default dflt_FlowControl;
    property StripNullChars : Boolean read fStripNullChars
                                      write SetStripNullChars
                                      default dflt_StripNullChars;
    property EOFChar : byte read fEOFChar
                            write SetEOFChar
                            default dflt_EOFChar;
    property OnTransmit : TNotifyTXEvent read fOnTransmit
                                         write fOnTransmit;
    property OnReceive : TNotifyRXEvent read fOnReceive
                                        write fOnReceive;
    property AfterTransmit : TNotifyTXEvent read fAfterTransmit
                                            write fAfterTransmit;
    property AfterReceive : TNotifyRXEvent read fAfterReceive
                                            write fAfterReceive;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

// Create method.
constructor TSerialPort.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  // Initalize the handle to the port as
  // an invalid handle value.  We do this
  // because the port hasn't been opened
  // yet, and it allows us to test for
  // this condition in some functions,
  // thereby controlling the behavior
  // of the function.
  //TSerialPort.Create(AOwner);
  hCommPort := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

  // Set initial settings.  Even though
  // the default parameter was specified
  // in the property, if you were to
  // create a component at runtime, the
  // defaults would not get set.  So it
  // is important to call them again in
  // the create of the component.
  fCommPort := dflt_CommPort;
  fBaudRate := dflt_BaudRate;
  fParityType := dflt_ParityType;
  fParityErrorChecking := dflt_ParityErrorChecking;
  fParityErrorChar := dflt_ParityErrorChar;
  fParityErrorReplacement := dflt_ParityErrorReplacement;
  fStopBits := dflt_StopBits;
  fDataBits := dflt_DataBits;
  fXONChar := dflt_XONChar;
  fXOFFChar := dflt_XOFFChar;
  fXONLim := dflt_XONLim;
  fXOFFLim := dflt_XOFFLim;
  fErrorChar := dflt_ErrorChar;
  fFlowControl := dflt_FlowControl;
  fStripNullChars := dflt_StripNullChars;
  fEOFChar := dflt_EOFChar;
  //fOnTransmit := nil;
  //fOnReceive := nil;
end;

// Public method to open the port and
// assign the handle to it.
function TSerialPort.OpenPort(MyCommPort : TCommPort) : Boolean;
var
  MyPort : PChar;
begin
  // Make sure that the port is Closed first.
  ClosePort;

  MyPort := PChar('COM' + IntToStr(ord(fCommPort)+1));
  hCommPort := CreateFile(MyPort,
                          GENERIC_READ OR GENERIC_WRITE,
                          0,
                          nil,
                          OPEN_EXISTING,
                          0,0);
  // Initialize the port.
  Initialize_DCB;
  // Was successful if not and invalid handle.
  result := hCommPort <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
end;

// Public method to Close the port.
function TSerialPort.ClosePort : boolean;
begin
  FlushTX;
  FlushRX;
  // Close the handle to the port.
  result := CloseHandle(hCommPort);
  hCommPort := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
end;

// Public Send data method.
procedure TSerialPort.SendData(data : PChar; size : DWord);
var
  NumBytesWritten : DWord;
begin

  if hCommPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;

  if assigned(fOnTransmit) then fONTransmit(self, Data);

  WriteFile(hCommPort,
            Data^,
            Size,
            NumBytesWritten,
            nil);

  // Fire the transmit event.
  if assigned(fAfterTransmit) then fAfterTransmit(self, Data);
end;

function TSerialPort.InputBufferCount: LongInt;
var
    oStatus: TComStat;
    dwErrorCode: DWord;
begin
    Result := 0;

    if hCommPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
        Exit;

    ClearCommError(hCommPort, dwErrorCode, @oStatus);
        Result := oStatus.cbInQue;
end;


// Public Get data method.
function TSerialPort.GetData : String;
var
  NumBytesRead : DWord;
  // <<cbInQue>> Specifies the number
  // of bytes received by the serial
  // provider but not yet read by a
  // ReadFile operation.
  BytesInQueue : LongInt;  // Number of bytes in the input buffer
        oStatus: TComStat;       // Variable for the ComStat structure.
        dwErrorCode: DWord;      // Variable to put the error codes in.
begin
  if hCommPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;

  if assigned(fOnReceive) then fONReceive(self, ReadBuffer);
  // Get the total number of bytes that
  // are waiting to be read from the
  // input buffer.
  ClearCommError(hCommPort, dwErrorCode, @oStatus);
        BytesInQueue := oStatus.cbInQue;

        if BytesInQueue > 0 then begin
                SetLength(ReadBuffer, BytesInQueue + 1);
                ReadFile(hCommPort,
             PChar(ReadBuffer)^,
             BytesInQueue,
             NumBytesRead,
             nil);
                SetLength(ReadBuffer, StrLen(PChar(ReadBuffer)));
        end;

  if assigned(fAfterReceive) then fAfterReceive(self, ReadBuffer);
  result := ReadBuffer;
end;



// Destroy method.
destructor TSerialPort.Destroy;
begin
  // Close the port first;
  ClosePort;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

// Initialize the device control block.
procedure TSerialPort.Initialize_DCB;
var
  MyDCB : TDCB;
  //file://MyCommTimeouts : TCommTimeouts;
begin

  // Only want to perform the setup
  // if the port has been opened and
  // the handle assigned.
  if hCommPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;

  // The GetCommState function fills in a
  // device-control block (a DCB structure)
  // with the current control settings for
  // a specified communications device.
  // (Win32 Developers Reference)
  // Get a default fill of the DCB.
  GetCommState(hCommPort, MyDCB);

  case fBaudRate of
    br110 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 110;
    br300 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 300;
    br600 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 600;
    br1200 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 1200;
    br2400 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 2400;
    br4800 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 4800;
    br9600 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 9600;
    br14400 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 14400;
    br19200 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 19200;
    br38400 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 38400;

    br56000 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 56000;
    br128000 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 128000;
    br256000 : MyDCB.BaudRate := 256000;
  end;

  // Parity error checking parameters.
  case fParityType of
    pcNone : MyDCB.Parity := NOPARITY;
    pcEven : MyDCB.Parity := EVENPARITY;
    pcOdd : MyDCB.Parity := ODDPARITY;
    pcMark : MyDCB.Parity := MARKPARITY;
    pcSpace : MyDCB.Parity := SPACEPARITY;
  end;
  if fParityErrorChecking then inc(MyDCB.Flags, $0002);
  if fParityErrorReplacement then inc(MyDCB.Flags, $0021);
  MyDCB.ErrorChar := char(fErrorChar);

  case fStopBits of
    sbOne : MyDCB.StopBits := ONESTOPBIT;
    sbOnePtFive : MyDCB.StopBits := ONE5STOPBITS;
    sbTwo : MyDCB.StopBits := TWOSTOPBITS;
  end;

  case fDataBits of
    db4 : MyDCB.ByteSize := 4;
    db5 : MyDCB.ByteSize := 5;
    db6 : MyDCB.ByteSize := 6;
    db7 : MyDCB.ByteSize := 7;
    db8 : MyDCB.ByteSize := 8;
  end;

  // The 'flags' are bit flags,
  // which means that the flags
  // either turn on or off the
  // desired flow control type.
  case fFlowControl of
    fcXON_XOFF : MyDCB.Flags := MyDCB.Flags or $0020 or $0018;
    fcRTS_CTS : MyDCB.Flags := MyDCB.Flags or $0004 or
$0024*RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
    fcDSR_DTR : MyDCB.Flags := MyDCB.Flags or $0008 or
$0010*DTR_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
  end;

  if fStripNullChars then inc(MyDCB.Flags,$0022);

  MyDCB.XONChar := Char(fXONChar);
  MyDCB.XOFFChar := Char(fXONChar);

  // The XON Limit is the number of
  // bytes that the data in the
  // receive buffer must fall below
  // before sending the XON character,
  // there for resuming the flow
  // of data.
  MyDCB.XONLim := fXONLim;
  // The XOFF limit is the max number
  // of bytes that the receive buffer
  // can contain before sending the
  // XOFF character, therefore
  // stopping the flow of data.
  MyDCB.XOFFLim := fXOFFLim;

  // Character that signals the end of file.
  if fEOFChar <> 0 then MyDCB.EOFChar := char(EOFChar);

  // The SetCommTimeouts function sets
  // the time-out parameters for all
  // read and write operations on a
  // specified communications device.
  // (Win32 Developers Reference)
  // The GetCommTimeouts function retrieves
  // the time-out parameters for all read
  // and write operations on a specified
  // communications device.
  // GetCommTimeouts(hCommPort, MyCommTimeouts);
  // MyCommTimeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout := ...
  // MyCommTimeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier := ...
  // MyCommTimeouts.etc...................
  // SetCommTimeouts(hCommPort, MyCommTimeouts);

  SetCommState(hCommPort, MyDCB);
end;

// Set the comm port.
procedure TSerialPort.SetCommPort(CP : TCommPort);
begin
  if fCommPort <> CP then begin <------------- Here is where access violation happens
    fCommPort := CP;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the baud rate.
procedure TSerialPort.SetBaudRate(BR : TBaudRate);
begin

  if fBaudRate <> BR then begin
    fBaudRate := BR;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the parity check type.
procedure TSerialPort.SetParityType(PT : TParityType);
begin
  if fParityType <> PT then begin
    fParityType := PT;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Do we want to do parity error checking?
procedure TSerialPort.SetParityErrorChecking(SPEC : Boolean);
begin
  if fParityErrorChecking <> SPEC then begin
    fParityErrorChecking := SPEC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the parity error char.
procedure TSerialPort.SetParityErrorChar(PEC : Byte);
begin
  if fParityErrorChar <> PEC then begin
    fParityErrorChar := PEC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set wether to replace parity errors with error char.
procedure TSerialPort.SetParityErrorReplacement(PER : Boolean);
begin
  if fParityErrorReplacement <> PER then begin
    fParityErrorReplacement := PER;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the stop bits.
procedure TSerialPort.SetStopBits(SSB : TStopBits);
begin
  if fStopBits <> SSB then begin
    fStopBits := SSB;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the data bits.
procedure TSerialPort.SetDataBits(SDB : TDataBits);
begin
  if fDataBits <> SDB then begin
    fDataBits := SDB;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the XON Char.
procedure TSerialPort.SetXONChar(SXC : byte);
begin
  if fXONChar <> SXC then begin
    fXONChar := SXC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the XOFF Char.
procedure TSerialPort.SetXOFFChar(SXOC : byte);
begin
  if fXOFFChar <> SXOC then begin
    fXOFFChar := SXOC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the XON Limit.
procedure TSerialPort.SetXONLim(SXOL : word);
begin
  if fXONLim <> SXOL then begin
    fXONLim := SXOL;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the XOFF Limit.
procedure TSerialPort.SetXOFFLim(SXFL : word);
begin
  if fXOFFLim <> SXFL then begin
    fXOFFLim := SXFL;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the error character.
procedure TSerialPort.SetErrorChar(SEC : byte);
begin
  if fErrorChar <> SEC then begin
    fErrorChar := SEC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the type of flow control desired.
procedure TSerialPort.SetFlowControl(SFC : TFlowControl);
begin
  if fFlowControl <> SFC then begin
    fFlowControl := SFC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Do we want to strip off the null characters?
procedure TSerialPort.SetStripNullChars(SSNC : Boolean);
begin
  if fStripNullChars <> SSNC then begin
    fStripNullChars := SSNC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Set the EOF char.
procedure TSerialPort.SetEOFChar(SEOFC : Byte);
begin
  if fEOFChar <> SEOFC then begin
    fEOFChar := SEOFC;
    Initialize_DCB;
  end;
end;

// Public function to check if the port is open.
function TSerialPort.PortIsOpen : boolean;
begin
  Result := hCommPort <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
end;

// Public method to cancel and flush the receive buffer.
procedure TSerialPort.FlushRx;
begin
  if hCommPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;
  PurgeComm(hCommPort, PURGE_RXABORT or PURGE_RXCLEAR);
  ReadBuffer := '';
end;

// Public method to cancel and flush the transmit buffer.
procedure TSerialPort.FlushTx;
begin
  if hCommPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;
  PurgeComm(hCommPort, PURGE_TXABORT or PURGE_TXCLEAR);
end;

// Register the component in its own menu selection.
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Misc', [TSerialPort]);
end;

end.
```

The below information is sent to this Serial.pas:

```
function TfrmMain.SetCOMPort(Index:Integer;BaudRate:TBaudRate):Boolean;
var
TempPort:TCommPort;
begin
TempPort := cpCOM1;
If Index = 0 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM1;
If Index = 1 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM2;
If Index = 2 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM3;
If Index = 3 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM4;
If Index = 4 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM5;
If Index = 5 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM6;
If Index = 6 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM7;
If Index = 7 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM8;
If Index = 8 then
  TempPort:=cpCOM9;

MySP.CommPort := TempPort;
MySP.BaudRate := BaudRate;
Result := True; <----- don't know if this is correct
end;
```

Comment: Looks like instance of a class is already freed when you come to `.SendData()`

Comment: I declared it as private
    hCommPort: THandle;

Comment: @Vincent - Then Krom is right in all likelyhood.

Comment: I did some changes to my code(well took some code out of unit1.pas) and now that access violation by .SendData() on application exit does not come up anymore.

Comment: Its a Public method to cancel communication and flush the transmit buffer.

Comment: The only plausible explanation is that `Self` is invalid. Either `nil` or already destroyed.

Comment: Would that be related to the function TSerialPort.GetData : String; and the procedure TSerialPort.SendData(data : PChar; size : DWord);?

Comment: Did I post my question wrong for you people to downvote the post?

Comment: At the point where FlushTx executes, Self is invalid. Unless you show an SSCCE we cannot say more than that.

Comment: Can't say for all downvoters, but you are asking us to debug your code, which is .. generally your job. The error is quite trivial. Look through other AV questions here, they all are identical - accessing freed objects .. and yours one is not different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if hCommPort = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then exit;
```

An access violation occurs when you attempt to read or write an address that is invalid. In your code the only memory access is the field `hCommPort`. What this means is that the `Self` pointer, the instance reference, refers to an invalid address. Common causes for this include the instance reference is `nil` or refers to an object that has been destroyed.

With the information you provided it is not possible to say any more. You will have to debug your program to work out why `Self` is not valid.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my post again and put the entire Serial.pas file in.

Comment: I had 6 other access violations in my project, but I fixed 5 of then, this the only one that I am having at the moment.

Comment: I should also say the when I call this class Serial.pas I call it like so MySP: TSerialPort; and it gives me an error saying it has no corresponding component, remove declaration?

Comment: I have found my solution for why I was getting access violations, is that in my unit1.pas,
I declared MySP: TSerialPort; but I did not include it in my unit1.dfm file, so I edited it and it works 100%.

I found this out on this link:

http://forums.devshed.com/delphi-programming-90/help-component-179791.html